# Differences between Reveal-md and reveal.js + external markdown

Tags: markdown, reveal.js

On my search for a way to author presentations using markdown for fast authoring yet flexible and customizable presentations, I discovered [reveal.js](https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js) some weeks ago. Later on, I discovered [reveal-md](https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md) and while I like everything I am reading on the official documentation I am wondering about the differences between using `reveal.js` with external markdown and using `reveal-md`.

As far as I know, both options require compilation in order to generate the final html file, but if I am not wrong, `reveal.js` needs a barebone HTML file with the configuration while with `reveal-md` there is no need for such file. However, since I am pretty new to `reveal.js` I cannot yet appreciate the differences and where does `reveal-md` shine over the other method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from the original author at https://github.com/webpro/reveal-md/issues/217:

> I think you're describing the differences quite well. I think the main
>   advantages of reveal-md is that you only need a Markdown file, and it
>   starts a simple server so the presentation is available at e.g.
>   http://localhost:1543 automatically.
>
> Next to this, there are a few gimmicks such as using YAML front matter
>   for configuration options and Markdown pre-processing.